# GQL query from .Net Core application running on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Is there any way for querying google cloud datastore with GQL, haven't found any related functionality in recommended [official client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1). However python client got [this 
 feature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was able to find is http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/

The example that you are looking for is the last one in this link.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not really what I need and that's the way I am fetching datastore now. What I am looking for is the way for executing raw queries like: **select * from somekind**.
For example EF provides **dbContext.Entity.SqlQuery()** for that purpose.

Comment: Could you describe what kind of task requires such approach? Client library and provided query object interface doing the same things as string GQL.